# Is it possible to have ranges in two octets in an ACL / object-group

Tags: firewall, cisco-ios, acl

I'm trying to find out if there is a "clean" way to do this.

I need to setup a ACL on a FWSM that effects devices over multiple subnets.

The structure looks like this:
10.10.1-254.1-15

I could do:

```
object-group network example
 network-object 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.240
 ..
 ..
 network-object 10.10.254.0 255.255.255.240
```

but i'm hoping there a way to do this without having to add each subnet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly! I believe inverse masks were created to be dis-contiguous rather than a normal subnet mask that must be contiguous.

An ACL such as the following should do the trick on an **IOS device**.

Ip access-list [standard/extended] SUBNET_240
 permit ip 10.10.0.0 0.0.255.15

I am not familar with the FWSM but you should be able to create a similar ACL on an ASA.

I also just logged in to my **ASA 5512** and I was able to create a network object with a dis-contiguous mask (but not inverse).

192.168.0.0 255.255.0.240

Comment: I was way over thinking this haha. I'm guessing in the object-group the following would work -> network-object 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.240 ?

Comment: That is exactly what you need sir, please rate my answer if you found it helpful